# Can I travel to Kenya without a passport even though I'm a citizen?

Tags: ireland, kenya, kenyan-citizens

My passport got burned but I'm still obviously a dual Irish/Kenyan citizen. I have a valid Irish passport and was wondering if I booked a ticket from Dublin to Kenya, could I travel on my Irish passport and then show them proof of citizenship?

I just don't feel like paying €50 for a visa.

Comment: You might get away with that at the border, but the airline probably won't let you board the flight. Could you get a replacement Kenyan passport before you travel?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.